# Is there mocha reporter that logs console output, not test code?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js

I tried a lot of mocha reporters, that can create report HTML files, but none of them showed the console output for every test and just showed the source code of the test.

Why is that? The console output is the exact information that i want to see in my reports!

Tried:
- mocha-simple-html-reporter
- mochawesome
- .others maybe

The only reporter that shows the console output is the Intellij bundled one, but there is no way i can make it create test report html file for me with console command

Answer (score -1):

Mochawesome generates new reports for every spec we have. And since by default it overwrites old reports, this means it will only keep the last test spec run. 
This we can fix by setting the overwrite flag to false. Changing this flag to false would just generate a new file at each run.

So you should delete old ones before running, manually or by using some script:

```
{
 "reporter": "mochawesome",
 "reporterOptions": {
   "charts": false,
   "html": true,
   "json": true,
   "reportDir": "cypress/reports",
   "reportFilename": "report",
   "overwrite": true 
 }
}
```